# How can I adjust the name of a process I run?

Tags: linux, freebsd, process, top, rack

I have a rack/ruby application on a server. I run it as follows:

```
  nohup rackup -o 0.0.0.0 -p 1234 &
```

In the output of "top" command it appears as simply "ruby"

```
PID   USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME    WCPU COMMAND

98421  my_user123       3  20    0   140M 29576K select   0:29   0.01% ruby
```

How can I adjust its name in the "top"? What if I run 5 such web apps, how would I distinguish which is which if they're all "ruby"?

Comment: `What if I run 5 such web apps, how would I distinguish which is which if they're all "ruby"?` - Well... they'd all have a different PID.

Comment: @joeqwerty, I said - "how would I know which is which"

Answer (score 0):

It's not the process name you need to adjust, but your tool.

Press <kbd>c</kbd> while `top` is running, or just start it with `-c` to see full command lines.

For example, without `-c`:

```
12329 error     20   0  618748 202472  19424 S   0.0 20.0   7:49.32 ruby
```

And with `-c`:

```
12329 error     20   0  618748 202472  19424 S   0.0 20.0   7:49.32 ruby /home/error/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@app/bin/thin start -a ::1 -p 8008
```

Comment: on linux - yes, that's good. on freebsd - "command not understood". how to do that?

Comment: on linux - yes, that's good. on freebsd - "command not understood". how to do that?

Comment: On a `FreeBSD` just press `a` in the `top`. Or better run `ps auxwww | grep ruby`

Answer (score -1):

On systems where it is supported, you can change the name of a process in ruby by assigning to `$0` or by using [Process.setproctitle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Process.html#method-c-setproctitle) (ruby 2.1+).

Comment: `by assigning to $0` -- how?

Comment: @Kakki `$0 = "something"`

Comment: that doesn't work `$0 = "something" nohup rackup -o 0.0.0.0 -p 1234 &`. show the full command

Comment: @Kakki ... in the program, of course, not in the shell.

Comment: thx, I'll try to